# Javascript reference any number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a refresh button that only works on `/` page and `/page/*` page (where * can be any number).  Here is my code

```
$('.refresh a').click(function() {
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;
    if (pathName == '/' || pathName == '/page/*') {
        event.preventDefault();
        location.reload(true);
    }else {}
});
```

But this does not work at all, is there any way to make this work?

`window.location.pathname` can be `/page/1` or `/page/999/`, I need this to work on any page that begins with `/page`.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on your if statement what does `window.location.pathname` evaluate to? and also use `===` for comparison if you really don't know what you are doing. also the glob pattern doesn't really work here `'/page/*'` I think you need to use regex for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a regex ?

```
$('.refresh a').click(function() {
    var pathName = window.location.pathname;
    if (pathName == '/' || /^\/page\/\d+?\/?$/.test(pathName) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        location.reload(true);
    }else {}
});
```

That would match things like

```
/page/4
/page/4/
/page/11111111
```

but not

```
/page/test/
/page/1/ff
```

etc.

Comment: You beat me! you'd need an optional trailing slash as well as per OP's edit.